# How to save the table filled with class name as a html file in my local disk with js or php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```js
 

ob_submit = document.getElementById("submit");
function formatted(){
    var fobs = document.querySelectorAll("td input[type='text']");
    for(var i=0;i<fobs.length;i++){
        var myStr = fobs[i].value;
        var cell = fobs[i].parentNode;
        cell.removeChild(cell.childNodes[0]);
        cell.innerText = myStr;
    }
}
ob_submit.addEventListener("click",formatted);
```

```css
table,tr,td{
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>mon</td>
  <td>tue</td>
  <td>web</td>
  <td>thu</td>
  <td>fri</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>4</td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit">
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="button" value="saveas"   id="saveas">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have created a table with JavaScript code, you can input your class name in every inputs in `td`, click submit when you fill your all classes in the table for a week, it becomes a week's Class Schedule.

I want to write a `saveas` function with JS, to save the table filled with class names in `/home/classSchedule.html`, maybe JS can't write the table in my local disk, how can I fulfill the job with PHP instead?

[image]

The class schedule here, I need a `saveas` function to save it.
Html file is more readability than database,it can be saved in my smartphone and read it there.

Comment: You have to maintain a database to store these table data, when you click on save, this all data will be inserted into database table using PHP, and then it can be written on html by fetching the same data using PHP again.

Comment: is there a reason why you want to use just a local file instead of a database?

Comment: Html file is more readability than database,it can be saved in my smart phone,how can you read a database file in smartphone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following function to your js:

```
save_as = document.getElementById("saveas");

// this functions submits the html structure needed to be saved, via an ajax request
function generateHtmlFile(){

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {   // XMLHttpRequest.DONE == 4
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
            else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                alert('There was an error 400');
            }
            else {
                alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
            }
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "generate_html_file.php", true);

    // the style, in case it's needed in the output html page
    var style = '<style>table,tr,td{border:1px solid black;text-align:center;}</style>';

    // get all table rows, except the one that contains the buttons
    var my_table_children = document.querySelectorAll('#my_table tr:not(.buttons)');

    var my_table_html = '<table>';

    // loop over table rows to filter them from white spaces & line breaks.
    for(var i = 0; i < my_table_children.length; i++){

        my_table_html += my_table_children[i].outerHTML.replace(/>\s+</g, "><")
    }

    my_table_html += '</table>';

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('html',style + my_table_html);

    xmlhttp.send(data);
}
save_as.addEventListener("click",generateHtmlFile);
```

add an id to your table element:

`<table id="my_table">`

add a class to your buttons container row '':

`<tr class="buttons">`

so your html should be as follow:

```
<table id="my_table">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>mon</td>
        <td>tue</td>
        <td>web</td>
        <td>thu</td>
        <td>fri</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="buttons">
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit">
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="button" value="saveas"   id="saveas">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

then, here is the php script that generates the html file:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['html']))
{
    $html_file = fopen("html_output.html", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($html_file, $_POST['html']);
    fclose($html_file);

    echo "saved successfully";
}
else{

    echo "false";
}
```